# How to implement these classes if I want to have a factory?

Tags: java, factory, factory-pattern, composite

So I'm creating a "text document" program where you can add titles, paragraphs, lists etc to a document. The document will be printed to the console. My structure looks like this right now:

A component is an object that can be added to the document.

```
public abstract class Component {}
```

A paragraph is a component. There is also an identical "title" component which I wont show for simplicity.

```
public class ParagraphComponent extends Component {

    private String text;

    public ParagraphComponent(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("|PARAGRAPH|--> %s <--|PARAGRAPH|", text);
    }
}
```

A list is a composite of components.

```
public class ListComponent extends Component {

    private List<Component> components = new ArrayList();

    public void addComponent(Component component) {
        components.add(component);
    }

    public void addComponent(Component component, int index) {
        components.add(index, component);
    }

    public void removeComponent(int index) {
        components.remove(index);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "|LIST|-->\n" + components.stream()
                .map(p -> "\t" + p.toString())
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")) + "\n<--|LIST|";
    }
}
```

Running this works great

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    TitleComponent a = new TitleComponent("AAA");
    TitleComponent b = new TitleComponent("BBB");
    TitleComponent c = new TitleComponent("CCC");

    TitleComponent d = new TitleComponent("DDD");
    TitleComponent e = new TitleComponent("EEE");
    TitleComponent f = new TitleComponent("FFF");
    ListComponent list = new ListComponent();
    list.addComponent(d);
    list.addComponent(e);
    list.addComponent(f);
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
    System.out.println(c);
    System.out.println(list);
}

Output:
|TITLE|--> AAA <--|TITLE|
|TITLE|--> BBB <--|TITLE|
|TITLE|--> CCC <--|TITLE|
|LIST|-->
    |TITLE|--> DDD <--|TITLE|
    |TITLE|--> EEE <--|TITLE|
    |TITLE|--> FFF <--|TITLE|
<--|LIST|
```

Now to my question... I want to create a factory for components. The return type of the factory will of course be Component. This results in me not being able to use the methods defined in the concrete component classes, e.g. title.setText("A"); won't work since it's not defined in an interface or the abstract class. I also don't wont to define these in "Component" since a "title" can't add another Component to itself, and a List can't change it's own text... This would lead to methods that does nothing for different components. Do you have any idea how this could be implemented in a smart way? Notice I want a document to be represented by a list containing components. And these components should be editable after creation since I dont always want to instanciate them with a string.

Even if a factory is unnecessary here, the question stands. How can I structure the classes so that I can:

```
Component title = new TitleComponent();
title.setText("abc");
```

?

Comment: Why do you want a factory? What benefit do you expect from it?

Comment: It's maybe not required for the small application here, but I want to implement it to leave the instanciation to the factory so that the client doesn't need to know how to create a title. I'm learning how to use factories.

Comment: You may be missing some intermediate classes, or need default implementations of invalid methods, or... Factories are most useful when generating uniform is-a types; if it can generate instances with different underlying types then you'll still need to do casting somewhere down the line.